# Spring data cassandra - complex type value as json

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

I've seen both [Cassandra entities must have the @Table, @Persistent or @PrimaryKeyClass Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411059/cassandra-entities-must-have-the-table-persistent-or-primarykeyclass-annotat) and
[Build breaks when using cassandra entity with jodatime object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385533/build-breaks-when-using-cassandra-entity-with-jodatime-object) but I didn't find my answer there.

I'm using spring data cassandra 1.4.5.RELEASE on a spring boot application.
I'm trying to store a "complex type" as a JSON string into cassandra.

Here is the CQL to create my table "test":

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    co text
}
```

Here is my entity:

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.DataType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKey;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table;

import java.util.UUID;

@Table("test")
public class Test {

    @PrimaryKey("id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column("co")
    private ComplexObject co;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TEXT)
    public ComplexObject getCo() {
        return co;
    }

    public void setCo(ComplexObject co) {
        this.co = co;
    }

}
```

Here is my "complex object":

```
public class ComplexObject {
    private String value1;
    private String value2;

    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public void setValue1(String value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }

    public String getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }

    public void setValue2(String value2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
    }
}
```

Here is my repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.UUID;

public interface TestRepository extends CrudRepository<Test, UUID> {
}
```

When I start my application, I get the following error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.VerifierMappingExceptions:
>   ComplexObject: Cassandra entities must have the @Table, @Persistent or
>   @PrimaryKeyClass Annotation

What I want is my "complex object" to be stored in the text column "co" with its JSON representation.
I know Spring Data Cassandra doesn't support yet UDT, but I'm only asking for it to be stored as "text".

I've managed to store a Map> in a "text" column with a @ReadingConverter, @WritingConverter and custom MappingCassandraConverter to fix the issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-349

I want to do something very similar, but the problem isn't with the converters yet. Somehow, Spring Data Cassandra seems to believe that my "ComplexType" is a Cassandra entity when its not...

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: That's not possible as of 1.4. The upcoming 1.5 release (already available as `1.5.0.M1`) supports custom conversion, see [the converter example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/cassandra/example/src/main/java/example/springdata/cassandra/convert).

Comment: Ok thanks. But my problem isn't about conversion yet. Spring Data Cassandra recognize my "ComplexObject" as an entity when it's not... Is it still the same issue?

Comment: 1.5 addresses this issue. Types that can be converted (i.e. a registered converter was found) are treated as singular attributes (simple columns) and not as entities. This requires a type mapping to a Cassandra-supported type (`String`, blob, numerical value, …).

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot!